# Best way to use Require JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, oclazyload

I've been playing with require JS now.

This is my config,

```
var require = {
    baseUrl: 'app/',
    paths: {
        'angular': '../scripts/angular',
        'ui-router': '../scripts/angular-ui-router',
        'ocLazyLoad': '../scripts/ocLazyLoad.min',
    },
    shim: {
        'ui-router': {
            deps: ['angular'],
        },
        'ocLazyLoad': {
            deps: ['angular'],
        },
    }
};
```

> Why is it required to define this dependencies inorder for it to work.

```
define(['angular', 'ui-router', 'ocLazyLoad'], function () {
```

> Another question, lets just say i have bootstrap css that will be used
>   throughout the application, what is the best way to load it?

Comment: I can only suggest you to use Browserify :).

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin why u recommend it? is there advantage than using oclazyload and requirejs?

Comment: An interesting article: http://www.leanpanda.com/blog/2015/06/28/amd-requirejs-commonjs-browserify/ Mainly because it is easier and comfortable to use.